# How to send a parameter to controller method with javascript in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I send parameter from javascript to controller method ? For example I 'm trying to send parameter "2012"

Here is my script in my View:

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "get", url: "test", data: {}, // How can i fill this data like @item ?
                        success: function (data) {

                            alert(data);

                        }
```

my controller method:

```
public string test()
        {

            TestServices client = new TestServices();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "service_test";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "..";
            client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

            decimal? x = client.GetTest(2012, 7, 1);

            return (""+x);


        }
```

Comment: could you show me a simple example ? @Magrangs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]    
public string test(string name, string age)
```

And the ajax

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "get", url: "test", data: {name:"Messi",age:"36yo"}, // How can `i fill this data like @item ?`
                    success: function (data) {

                        alert(data);

                    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for example how can I send model paremeter data: {@model.id} ?